# new Fragment by newInstance,allways got wrong var value

Tags: java, android

I got a problem like title said.

```
public class NewsCategoryFragment extends Fragment{
    private String cateTitle;
    public static NewsCategoryFragment newInstance(String title){
        NewsCategoryFragment fragment = new NewsCategoryFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title",title);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        xfReaderService = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getReaderService();
        newsInfoBeanList = new ArrayList<>();

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        cateTitle = bundle.getString("title");
        //Log.i("fragment","Bundle ______ content:" + cateTitle);

    }
    privoid void method1(){log.i("..",cateTitle);...}
    privoid void method2(){log.i("..",cateTitle);...}
}
```

This is my code simple version.  I got 2 method need var `cateTitle`, but it is always return my wrong value( return the next fragment value).
How to resolve this? thanks for help.
And I'm curious, the `cateTitle` is private and non-static,why could I get next fragment's value?

This is how i use newInstance code:

```
mFragmentList.add(NewsCategoryFragment.newInstance("news"));
```

Comment: The code you have provide does not seems problematic . Please add code how are you using this fragment's `#newInstance()`.

Comment: @ADM I am added. :)

Comment: It's migic, that show the second fragment's value.it's shut down the viewpager cache can resolve this only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done like this check if you are making mistaking anywhere

this is my code for calling a `new Fragment` by `newInstance()`

```
new DynamicFragment().newInstance("VALUE_AM_PASSING");
```

Then am collecting this value inside a `DynamicFragment`

```
 public static DynamicFragment newInstance(String val) {
    DynamicFragment fragment = new DynamicFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("someValue", val);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

After this inside `onCreateView()` method retrieves the value like this

```
String tempString = getArguments().getString("someValue");
```

Hope this answer will help you.

Comment: i added how i use newInstance code. it's almost same to you, just dont have new .

Comment: @Joey do you have tabs in your code ?? If yes then what I am doing is I am not adding the fragment into any List I am just using FragmentStatePagerAdapter and according to tabs positions am just returning a new DynamicFragment() by newInstance

Comment: yes,  i am think about it,and plan to expose method in fragment,and manage fragment's var value at father's fragment. i think it will be work; :)

Comment: @Joey Thanks, and let me know if it works or not, otherwise will find a solution. Meanwhile don't forget to upvote the answer, it might help others :)